# How to include a .gif inside TikZ mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, mindmaps

I know that TikZ provides a mindmapping library. I am wondering if it is possible to insert a `*.gif` picture instead of writing text inside each child (circle). 
Any help will be appreciated in advance.

here is the sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=black]
    node[concept] {Motivation}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {practical} }
    child[concept color=blue, counterclockwise from=30] {
      node[concept,scale=1.2] {applied} }
    child[concept color=orange, counterclockwise from=60] { 
    node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now instead of "applied", I want to insert a `*.gif` image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You will most probably get more help, if you include some code in your question. I don't have a pre-written mindmap here to play around with. Please also show, what you have tried. `\includegraphics{}` for sure.

Comment: .gif is not supported

Comment: Convert `yourimage.gif` to `yourimage.png` and then `\includegraphics{yourimage}` instead of `applied`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use .gif with TikZ?

Comment: Is it possible to put TikZ mindmap on lower layer then add my gif image on top of that by manipulating the position of that?

Comment: @user2090491 You _can't_ use a `.gif`: you _have_ to convert to a format that pdfTeX (_etc._) support

Comment: Is ".gif" supposed to mean "animated elements"?

Comment: no, it is .gif image.

Comment: Then what is the problem with JLDiaz's solution?

Comment: I do not want a png image, I want to be a gif picture, so it will have motion.

Comment: Take a look at: http://dynamic-mathematics.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=25986